# MySQL Count the number of fields that don't contain a specific value and store it in another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables.

1) The **wfGroups** table contains fields

```
wfs1, wfs2, wfs3, ..., wfs13, wfs14, wfs15
```

which contain `text strings` or a `0` or `are blank if there is no value in the field`

2) The **wf** table contains a field titled

```
totalSteps
```

which I want to contain a `count of the number of fields from the wfGroups table that don't contain the "0" or blank values`

There is `one` wfGroups table row `for each wf table row` Each row in both tables has a `userId and wfId` field which help determine what data belongs together. I have about a thousand rows that the totalSteps value needs to be calculated for.

This query only needs to be run once, after that the fields will update themselves when changes are made, so speed isn't an issue.

I'm new to SQL and I'm completely at a loss where to even begin creating this query. I've found bits and pieces of code that may prove useful, but I don't know how to put it all together and make it loop through every row storing the calculated values along the way.

Comment: can you give some sample to me from your tables and what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an update with a join:

```
update wf w
join wfgroups g on g.userId = w.userId and g.wfId = w.wfId
set w.totalSteps = wfs1 not in ("0", "") + wfs2 not in ("0", "") + wfs3 not in ("0", "")
+ wfs4 not in ("0", "") + wfs5 not in ("0", "") + wfs6 not in ("0", "")
+ wfs7 not in ("0", "") + wfs8 not in ("0", "") + wfs9 not in ("0", "")
+ wfs10 not in ("0", "") + wfs11 not in ("0", "") + wfs12 not in ("0", "")
+ wfs13 not in ("0", "") + wfs14 not in ("0", "") + wfs15 not in ("0", "");
```

This works because in mysql `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`,so by adding conditions, you get the number of times they are `true`.

Comment: This is good! But I need to count the number of times that a "0" or "" don't appear in fields... this looks like it'll count the number of times they DO appear. Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @Darren sorry, I misread your question. I have updated the answer to count the number of time `"0"` or `""` do *not* appear